# Connecting arbitrary streams to standard input

Tags: java, unit-testing, stream, pipe

I have a program that needs to process data from Standard-In.  I can call it on the command line like so `java program < input`.  I want to write a proper unit test for its main().  Is it possible to reassociate a method's System.in with some other stream?

In the test, I can read the sample data, and then somehow run the original program with its stdin connected to some stream that i define (from the sample data) and verify that it returns what i expect. I considered using these classes:
[PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and 
[PipedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html). But it would require me to modify the original program to read from a PipedInputStream every time I test it.  Or I can isolate the stream reading into a function (eg. `parseStream(InputStream)` ) and pass a PipedInputStream which is already connected to the sample data.

I can also write a shell script to pipe whatever i want into its stdin, but the method in question will be a part of a series of processing steps so it shouldn't itself write to stdout and actually returns ArrayList<SomeCompositeType>. Where SomeCompositeType contains the data that was read in a structured way (eg. some ints, arrays, Maps, etc..)

So is it possible to call some method that reads from System.in with a different stream?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider adding the stream to read from as an argument.

Comment: [`System.setIn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream))

Comment: +1 for @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams's approach: you shouldn't be changing `System.in` and `System.out`; you should be refactoring the code so you can pass it different streams to read from and write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031048/connecting-arbitrary-streams-to-standard-input#comment16058320_12031048).

What you appear to want is provided by [`System.setIn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)) :-)